# VUE: Any secure friendly methods for compile remote components?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, websecurity

I don't talk about insecure **v-html**, never use it anyway 
I talk about **Vue.compile()** and how do it secure for us? Analogs, cases, ways?

My case: 
 Remote admin can change or create some functional component in Visual UI builder inside admin panel
 In our site, we have 500 online peoples
 When admin create new component, what we haven't in frontend build - we need **online** change new block and move it inside user screen **online**

How ways better than **Vue.compile()**?
What cases better, worse, or analog in other libs?

Comment: What kind of security is it supposed to be?

Comment: @EstusFlask anything better what we have now, without this XSS and cros problem
I wanna know, is I can solve this with better architecture without insecure solutions

Comment: I'm not sure what concern you try to address. Do you not trust admins? Then allowing them to touch components a mistake. Vue component can potentially evaluate arbitrary JS on client side, nothing can be done with it. If you want something that generates safe HTML regardless of the input then Vue is not an option.

Comment: Perhaps this may help you - https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/distributed-vue-applications-loading-components-via-http/